# Create .url file based on url input (special characters) with C#

Tags: c#, file, url, character, title

I am creating a program that creates .url files based on a url. The file is supposed to have the URL's html 'title' as name. With the content of the file being the url header. For example:

Input

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fRh_vgS2dFE
```

Output: File name

```
Justin Bieber - Sorry (PURPOSE : The Movement).url
```

Output: File content

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Tr0otuiQuU
```

however the problem arises when I insert songs like the one in the example. Since it has a character unsupported by filenames in Windows (:).

Code

```
string _Path = @"C:\Users\Public\Music\";
    private void bNewSong_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lbPlaylists.SelectedItem != null && lbPlaylists.SelectedItem.ToString() != "")
        {
            string songURL = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Enter song URL:", "New", lbPlaylists.SelectedItem.ToString(), 800, 450);
            if (songURL != "" && songURL.Contains(@"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="))
            {
                WebClient x = new WebClient();
                string source = x.DownloadString(songURL);
                string title = Regex.Match(source, @"\<title\b[^>]*\>\s*(?<Title>[\s\S]*?)\</title\>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups["Title"].Value;
                title = title.Remove(title.Length - 10);
                string fullPath = _Path + lbPlaylists.SelectedItem.ToString() + "\\" + title + ".url";

                if (!File.Exists(fullPath))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fullPath))
                    {
                        string app = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
                        writer.WriteLine("[InternetShortcut]");
                        writer.WriteLine("URL=" + songURL);
                        writer.Flush();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Song already in playlist.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter a new playlist name.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Select a playlist to add a song to.");
        }
    }
```

So my question is:

How do I format the title to be a acceptable file name?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace invalid characters returned by

```
Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars(v=vs.110).aspx

For example:

```
foreach (var c in Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars())
    fullPath = fullPath.Replace(c, '-');
```